# Temporarily disabling system center monitoring

Tags: windows-server-2008, system-center

Is there any way to disable/enable System Center 2012 monitoring from the command line or through some sort of .NET object? I have a series of tests I need to run after hours and I'd like to turn off the monitoring while they run to minimize the noise.

I found [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212870.aspx), but it has no references to how to do this via command line or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control maintenance mode using the SCOM PowerShell SDK.

Here is the cmdlet for enabling maintenance mode:
[Start-SCOMMaintenanceMode](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh545190.aspx)